# Post request requestbody Null file download Corrupted

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am downloading a Excel File, I did a  post request, In client side code i am specifying null then file downloading perfectly and when i am not specifying null in client side the file is downloading with data but showing corrupted file while opening it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void downloadTemplateFiles(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            ServletOutputStream myOut;
            BufferedInputStream buf;
            myOut = response.getOutputStream();
            ClassPathResource inputFile = new ClassPathResource("excel/Temp.xlsx");
            InputStream input = inputFile.getInputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + inputFile.getFilename() + "\"");
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int readBytes;
            while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
                myOut.write(readBytes);
            }
            myOut.flush();
            myOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

```
 const generate = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('download',null, {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            });
            if (response.status === 200) {
                downloadFile(response.data, 'Temp.xlsx', "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                message.success("Report Template Dowloaded Successfully")
            } else {
                message.error("Error dowloading report.");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error downloading report:", error);
            message.error("Error downloading report.");
        }
    };
    const downloadFile = (content, filename, Type) => {
        const blob = new Blob([content], { type: Type });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    };
```

I used get it is fine now working and also while i am using post with null it is working then what is the problem i dont mention null it is getting corrupted.

Comment: Need more information. share the sample code, for both server and client

Comment: @sidgate I have posted the code